# GetElementByID Problem in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

This code fails in IE and Chrome on the following line:

```
top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid).innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
```

this code works perfectly in firefox 4.  The AJAX ASP Page like_status.asp works flawlessly and just returns some HTML code to be displayed in the page.

Here is the complete javascript code:

```
function LikeSU(statusid,option,mediaid)
{
     if (option == 'l')
     {
          document.getElementById('fmeProcess').src = '/ajax/like_unlike.asp?statusid=' + statusid + '&mediaid=' + mediaid + '&option=' + option;
          document.getElementById('StatusLike' + statusid).innerHTML = '&nbsp;&middot; <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LikeSU(' + statusid + ',\'u\')">Unlike</a>'
          GetLikeDisplay(statusid);
     }
     else
     {
          document.getElementById('fmeProcess').src = '/ajax/like_unlike.asp?statusid=' + statusid + '&mediaid=' + mediaid + '&option=' + option;
          document.getElementById('StatusLike' + statusid).innerHTML = '&nbsp;&middot; <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LikeSU(' + statusid + ',\'l\')">Like</a>'
          GetLikeDisplay(statusid);
     }
}

function GetLikeDisplay(statusid)
{
     var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
     var url="/ajax/like_status.asp?statusid=" + statusid
     if (!xmlHttp){
          alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
          return
     }
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
          if (xmlHttp.readyState == 1)
          {
               top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid).innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-left:5px"><img src="/images/register_loading.gif" alt="Loading"/></td><td style="color:#c0c0c0;padding-left:8px">Loading...</td></tr></table>';
          }
          if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete")
          {
               if(xmlHttp.responseText == "NoLikes")
               {
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid).innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeCountDisplay' + statusid).style.display = 'none';
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid + 'Gap').style.display = 'none';
               }
               else
               {
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeCountDisplay' + statusid).style.display = '';
                    top.document.getElementById('LikeStatusBar' + statusid + 'Gap').style.display = '';
               }
          }
     };
     xmlHttp.open("GET", url , true)
     xmlHttp.send(null)
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
     var objXMLHttp=null;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
          objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else if (window.ActiveXObject)
     {
          objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     return objXMLHttp;
}
```

any ideas as to how I can fix this problem in IE and Chrome..

Many thanks in advance,
Paul

ADDED CODE

```
 <!--#include virtual="/inc/global.asp"-->
 <% IF NOT UserIsLoggedIn() THEN %>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 top.parent.location.href = '/';
 </script>
 <% END IF %>
 <!--#include virtual="/inc/adovbs.inc"-->
 <!--#include virtual="/inc/common.inc"-->
 <%
 Dim pstrOut, MemberID, paryFriendStatus, StatusUpdate
 cData.SQL = "sp_MemberConnection " _
           & cData.ProcFld("MODE","RECENTFRIENDUSERSTATUSPOSTS",2,True) _
           & cData.ProcFld("MemberID",cSession.MemberID,0,False)
 paryFriendStatus = cData.RSArray()

 IF isArray(paryFriendStatus) THEN
   pstrOut = "<table border=""0"" width=""555"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">" & vbCr
   FOR i = 0 TO uBound(paryFriendStatus,2)
     pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr id=""MemberStatus" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr _
             & "<td style=""padding:4px 0px 4px 0px"">" & vbCr _
             & "<table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""100%"">" & vbCr _
             & "<tr>" & vbCr
     IF ISNULL(paryFriendStatus(6,i)) THEN
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""width: 75px"" valign=""top"" align=""center"">" & GetMemberAvatar(paryFriendStatus(0,i),C_SMALLAVATAR,True,True) & "</td>" & vbCr
     ELSE
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""width: 75px"" valign=""top"" align=""center"">" & GetMemberAvatar(paryFriendStatus(6,i),C_SMALLAVATAR,True,True)  & "</td>" & vbCr
     END IF
     pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td valign=""top"" class=""mainlink f5"">" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCr _
             & "<tr>" & vbCr
     IF paryFriendStatus(2,i) = "has joined Storeboard!" OR paryFriendStatus(2,i) = "joined Storeboard!" THEN
       StatusUpdate = DisplayName(paryFriendStatus(0,i)) & " joined Storeboard!"
     ELSE
       StatusUpdate = paryFriendStatus(2,i)
     END IF
     IF ISNULL(paryFriendStatus(6,i)) THEN
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""font-size:13px""><b style=""color:#0389BB"">" & MemberLink(paryFriendStatus(0,i),"BlueLink1") & ":</b>&nbsp;<span class=""mainlink-u"">" & FindLinks(StatusUpdate) & "</span></td>" & vbCr
     ELSE
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""font-size:13px"">" & vbCr _
               & "<div style=""float:left"">" & vbCr _
               & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"">" & vbCr _
               & "<tr>" & vbCr _
               & "<td><b style=""color:#0389BB"">" & MemberLink(paryFriendStatus(6,i),"BlueLink1") & "</b></td>" & vbCr _
               & "<td style=""padding:0px 4px 0px 4px""><img src=""/images/m2b_arrow.gif"" alt=""Arrow""/></td>" & vbCr _
               & "<td><b style=""color:#0389BB"">" & MemberLink(paryFriendStatus(0,i),"BlueLink1") & ":</b>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCr _
               & "</tr></table></div>" & vbCr _
               & "<div style=""float:left""><span class=""mainlink-u"">" & FindLinks(StatusUpdate) & "</span></div></td>" & vbCr
     END IF
     pstrOut = pstrOut & "</tr>" & vbCr

     SET DbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
     DbConn.Open DSN_LINK

     SET oRSbn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
     strSQLCount = "SELECT count(*) as comment_count FROM StatusComments WHERE MemberStatusID = " & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ";"
     oRSbn.open strSQLCount, DbConn
     nTotalComments = oRSbn("comment_count")
     oRSbn.Close

     IF cSession.MemberID = "33" OR cSession.MemberID = "102" THEN
       IF FetchLikeStatus(cSession.MemberID,paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = "" THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:25px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td class=""mainlink f5""><span style=""color:#808080"">" & HowLongAgo(paryFriendStatus(4,i))  & "</span><span id=""StatusLike" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""LikeSU(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ",'l')"">Like</a></span>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Comment</a>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ConfirmStatusRemoval(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Remove</a>" & vbCr
       ELSE
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:25px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td class=""mainlink f5""><span style=""color:#808080"">" & HowLongAgo(paryFriendStatus(4,i))  & "</span><span id=""StatusLike" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""LikeSU(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ",'u')"">Unlike</a></span>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Comment</a>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ConfirmStatusRemoval(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Remove</a>" & vbCr
       END IF
       IF nTotalComments > 3 THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""#"">View all " & nTotalComments & " comments</a>" & vbCr
       END IF
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "</td>" & vbCr _
               & "</tr>" & vbCr
     ELSE
       IF FetchLikeStatus(cSession.MemberID,paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = "" THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:25px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td class=""mainlink f5""><span style=""color:#808080"">" & HowLongAgo(paryFriendStatus(4,i))  & "</span><span id=""StatusLike" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""LikeSU(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ",'l')"">Like</a></span>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Comment</a>" & vbCr
       ELSE
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:25px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td class=""mainlink f5""><span style=""color:#808080"">" & HowLongAgo(paryFriendStatus(4,i))  & "</span><span id=""StatusLike" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""LikeSU(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ",'u')"">Unlike</a></span>&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Comment</a>" & vbCr
       END IF
       IF cLng(paryFriendStatus(0,i)) = cLng(cSession.MemberID) THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""ConfirmStatusRemoval(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"">Remove</a>" & vbCr
       END IF
       IF nTotalComments > 3 THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""#"">View all " & nTotalComments & " comments</a>" & vbCr
       END IF
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "</td></tr>" & vbCr
     END IF
     Set ShowComments = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
     IF nTotalComments >= 3 THEN
       nNumToShow = 3
     ELSEIF nTotalComments = 2 THEN
       nNumToShow = 2
     ELSE
       nNumToShow = 1
     END IF

     ' SHOW LIKE COUNTER
     IF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) > 0 THEN
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr id=""LikeCountDisplay" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr
     ELSE
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr id=""LikeCountDisplay" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """ style=""display:none"">" & vbCr
     END IF
     pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td>" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:350px"">" & vbCr _
             & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"" id=""LikeStatusBar" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr
     IF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) > 0 THEN
       IF FetchLikeStatus(cSession.MemberID,paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = "" THEN
         IF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = 1 THEN
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td><img src=""/images/thumbup_blue.gif"" alt=""Likes""/></td><td style=""padding-left:5px"" class=""f5 mainlink""><a href=""" & MemberURL(FetchOneLikeMember(paryFriendStatus(5,i))) & """>" & DisplayName(FetchOneLikeMember(paryFriendStatus(5,i))) & "</a> Likes This.</td></tr></table>" & vbCr
         ELSE
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td><img src=""/images/thumbup_blue.gif"" alt=""Likes""/></td><td style=""padding-left:5px"" class=""f5"">" & CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) & " Members Like This.</td></tr></table>" & vbCr
         END IF
       ELSE
         IF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = 1 THEN
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td><img src=""/images/thumbup_blue.gif"" alt=""Likes""/></td><td style=""padding-left:5px"" class=""f5"">You Like This</td></tr></table>" & vbCr
         ELSEIF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) = 2 THEN
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td><img src=""/images/thumbup_blue.gif"" alt=""Likes""/></td><td style=""padding-left:5px"" class=""f5"">You And <a href=""" & MemberURL(FetchOneLikeMember(paryFriendStatus(5,i))) & """>" & DisplayName(FetchOneLikeMember(paryFriendStatus(5,i))) & "</a> Like This.</td></tr></table>" & vbCr
         ELSE
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0""><tr><td><img src=""/images/thumbup_blue.gif"" alt=""Likes""/></td><td style=""padding-left:5px"" class=""f5"">You And " & CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) - 1 & " Members Likes This.</td></tr></table>" & vbCr
         END IF
       END IF
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "</td></tr>" & vbCr
       IF CountStatusLikes(paryFriendStatus(5,i)) > 0 THEN
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:2px;background-color:#FFFFFF"" id=""LikeStatusBar" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & "Gap"">" & vbCr
       ELSE
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""height:2px;background-color:#FFFFFF;display:none"" id=""LikeStatusBar" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & "Gap"">" & vbCr
       END IF
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td></td></tr></table></td></tr>" & vbCr
     ELSE
       pstrOut = pstrOut & "<td style=""padding:5px;border-bottom:1px #D8EEEE solid"">&nbsp;</td></tr>" & vbCr _
               & "<tr style=""height:2px;background-color:#FFFFFF;display:none"" id=""LikeStatusBar" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & "Gap"">" & vbCr _
               & "<td></td></tr></table></td></tr>" & vbCr
     END IF

     strSQL = "SELECT TOP " & nNumToShow & " * FROM StatusComments WHERE MemberStatusID = " & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & " ORDER BY StatusCommentTime ASC;"
     ShowComments.open strSQL, DbConn
     IF NOT ShowComments.EOF THEN
       ShowComments.MoveFirst
       Do while NOT ShowComments.EOF
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr id=""StatusComment" & ShowComments("StatusCommentID") & """>" & vbCr _
                 & "<td>" & vbCr _
                 & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:350px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td style=""padding-top:4px;width:50px"" align=""center"" valign=""top"">" & GetMemberAvatar(ShowComments("MemberID"),C_TINYAVATAR,False,False) & "</td>" & vbCr _
                 & "<td valign=""top"" style=""padding:3px 4px 3px 0px"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "<td><b style=""color:#0389BB"">" & MemberLink(ShowComments("MemberID"), "BlueLink1") & ":</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;" & FindLinks(ShowComments("StatusComment")) & "</td>" & vbCr _
                 & "</tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "<tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "<td style=""color:#777777"">" & HowLongAgo(ShowComments("StatusCommentTime"))
         IF cLng(paryFriendStatus(0,i)) = cLng(cSession.MemberID) OR cLng(ShowComments("MemberID")) = cLng(cSession.MemberID) THEN
           pstrOut = pstrOut & "&nbsp;&middot; <a href=""#"" onclick=""ConfirmStatusCommentDelete(" & ShowComments("StatusCommentID") & ")"">Delete</a>" & vbCr
         END IF
         pstrOut = pstrOut & "</td>" & vbCr _
                 & "</tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "</table>" & vbCr _
                 & "</td>" & vbCr _
                 & "</tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "<tr style=""height:2px;background-color:#FFFFFF"">" & vbCr _
                 & "<td></td>" & vbCr _
                 & "</tr>" & vbCr _
                 & "</table>" & vbCr _
                 & "</td>" & vbCr _
                 & "</tr>" & vbCr
         ShowComments.movenext
       loop
     END IF
     ShowComments.Close
     SET ShowComments = Nothing
     SET DbConn = Nothing
     pstrOut = pstrOut & "<tr style=""display:none"" id=""ShowComment" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr _
             & "<td>" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:350px"">" & vbCr _
             & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"">" & vbCr _
             & "<td style=""padding-top:4px;width:50px"" align=""center"" valign=""top"">" & GetMemberAvatar(cSession.MemberID,C_TINYAVATAR,False,False) & "</td>" & vbCr _
             & "<td valign=""top"" style=""padding:4px 4px 4px 0px"">" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCr _
             & "<tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<td id=""Comment" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """></td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<td style=""color:#777777"" id=""CommentTime" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """></td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "</table>" & vbCr _
             & "</td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "</table>" & vbCr _
             & "</td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<td>" & vbCr _
             & "<form action="""" method=""post"" name=""frmStatusComment" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr _
             & "<input type=""hidden"" value=""" & cSession.MemberID & """ name=""hidMemberID" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """/>" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""4"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:350px"" id=""nocomment" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"">" & vbCr _
             & "<td align=""center""><input type=""text"" onclick=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"" style=""padding-left:3px;height:20px;width:337px;border:1px #C6E7E7 solid;color:#808080"" class=""f5"" value=""Write a Comment!""/></td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "</table>" & vbCr _
             & "<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" style=""width:350px;display:none"" id=""yescomment" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"">" & vbCr _
             & "<td style=""padding-top:4px;width:50px"" align=""center"" valign=""top"">" & GetMemberAvatar(cSession.MemberID,C_TINYAVATAR,False,False) & "</td>" & vbCr _
             & "<td valign=""top"" style=""padding:4px 4px 0 0""><textarea id=""taStatusComments" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """ name=""taStatusComments" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & """ onblur=""ShowCommentBox(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")"" style=""padding:3px;width:290px;border:1px #C6E7E7 solid"" class=""f5"" cols="""" rows=""""></textarea></td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr style=""background-color:#EAF6F6"">" & vbCr _
             & "<td colspan=""2"" align=""right""><button type=""button"" class=""smlBtn"" name=""btnUpdate"" onclick=""return SaveStatusComments(" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & ")""><span class=""sBtn""><span class=""sBtn"">Comment</span></span></button></td>" & vbCr _
             & "</tr></table></form></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr>" & vbCr _
             & "<tr id=""MemberStatus" & paryFriendStatus(5,i) & "spacer"" style=""height:1px"">" & vbCr _
             & "<td style=""background-color:#E9E9E9""><img src=""/images/pixel.gif"" alt=""""/></td></tr>" & vbCr
   NEXT
   pstrOut = pstrOut & "</table>" & vbCr
   'Response.Write pstrOut
   'Response.End
 END IF %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
 <title>Untitled Page</title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 var target = top.parent.document.getElementById('fmeFriendStatus');
 var jstr = '';
 <%=cUtil.ToJS(pstrOut,"jstr")%>
 target.innerHTML = jstr;
 //-->
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This html page is ran in an iframe.. The majority is Classic ASP hence the double ""

Comment: Describe what you mean by "This code fails"...

Comment: What is top.document name of iFrame ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, based on the code provided, I think you would find jQuery / another JS framework a valuable addition with the amount of DOM manipulation you are doing.

Comment: SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation. 
like.js, line 32 character 16

Comment: I used top.document. for testing... usually it would be just document.

Comment: There are no iframes involved..

Comment: How about showing us your HTML?

Comment: I have added the code for the HTML onto the original post

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using 'window.top...'

instead of

'top....'

Some browsers are really strict in the DOM naming hierarchy.

Comment: This didn't make any difference.. sorry!

Comment: @neojakey I would try disassembling the whole line so you 'get' the element first & then try to set the innerHTML. Atleast that way it would tell you what is failing, the getting of the element or the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use top.document.all.elementName in IE. it works. But the problem cannot work in Firefox.